# flex close browser window without warning

Tags: apache-flex, browser

I want to use a button to close the browser without warning in Flex. But current solution I use close the browser with the warning on a button click. May I know how to close a browser window without warning? My code is like below:

```
private function closeWindow():void
        {
            urlString = "javascript:window.close();";               
            request = new URLRequest(urlString);
            navigateToURL(request, "_self");        
        }

    <s:Button id="Close" x="65" y="361" label="Close Window" click="closeWindow()"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried using ExternalInterface.call to invoke javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't close browser windows without warning this way due to browser security settings.